# How to write query/create view to limit multiple records to show only max value

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Consider the following three tables. A list of contacts, a list of status with a defined "rank" and a join table that links a contact to multiple status's.

```
   CREATE TABLE public."Contacts"
   (
     name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
     email character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
     contactid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Contacts_contactid_seq"'::regclass),
     CONSTRAINT "Contacts_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (contactid)
   )
   CREATE TABLE public.statusoptions
   (
     option character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
     "Rank" integer,
     CONSTRAINT "ListOptions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (option)
   )

   CREATE TABLE public."ContactStatus"
   (
     contactid integer NOT NULL,
     option character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT "Options_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (contactid, option),
     CONSTRAINT fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (contactid)
      REFERENCES public."Contacts" (contactid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fk_2 FOREIGN KEY (option)
    REFERENCES public.statusoptions (option) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    )
```

The following query returns all rows.

```
  select "Contacts".contactid, "Contacts".name, "ContactStatus".option, statusoptions."Rank" as 
  currentRank
  from "Contacts","ContactStatus", statusoptions
  where "Contacts".contactid = "ContactStatus".contactid
   and statusoptions.option="ContactStatus".option
```

This returns a record set that looks like this:

```
          Contactid name        Status          CurrentRank
           1        "john"      "apply"             1
           1        "john"      "Manager Review"    4
           2        "bill"      "apply"             1
           2        "bill"      "1st interview"     2
           1        "john"      "1st interview"     2
```

What I need is to create a query/view that would always JUST return the rows of the MAX current RANK. So the expected result I want from this view is:

```
         Contactid      name        Status          CurrentRank
          1           "john"        "Manager Review"    4
          2           "bill"        "1st interview"     2
```

At any time, I could change the "Rank" value in the statusoptions field, which would change the view accordingly.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use distinct on:

```
select distinct on(c.contactid)
    c.contactid, 
    c.name, 
    cs.option, 
    s."Rank" as currentRank
from 
    "Contacts" c
    inner join "ContactStatus" cs on c.contactid = cs.contactid
    inner join statusoptions s on s.option = cs.option
order by c.contactid, s."Rank" desc
```

Note:

- always use explicit, standard joins (with the `on` clause) instead of old-school, implicit joins (with a comma in the `where` clause)
- (short) table aliase make the query shorter and easier to read
- consider avoiding quoting table and column names, unless when absolutly necessary; they make the identifiers case-senstive, while by default they are not

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can use `distinct on`

I think you want:

```
select distinct on (c.contactid) c.contactid, c.name, cs.option, so."Rank" as currentRank
from "Contacts" c join
     "ContactStatus" cs
     on c.contactid = cs.contactid join
     statusoptions so
     on so.option = cs.option
order by c.contactid, so.rank desc;
```

Notes:

- Use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- Table aliases make a query easier to write and to read.
- You should avoid quoting table names and column names.  That just clutters up queries unnecessarily.
- `distinct on` usually has better performance than alternatives such as `row_number()`.

Comment: Thx! Exactly what I was looking for. I don't like to use quotes, but PGadmin complains about these tables If I don't put quotes around them.

Comment: @mikehennessy . . . They were defined with quotes, so the names are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can do **max**(rank) and **group by** the remaining fields

```
select c.contactid, c.name, cs.option, max(so.rank) currentRank 

from Contacts c
join ContactStatus cs on c.contactid = cs.contactid
join StatusOptions so on so.option = cs.option

group by c.contactid, c.name, cs.option
```